# Map/Loop over nested array in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have tried a few ways now and it only confuses me more, probably still above my knowledge but trying to get the the following to work:

I am pulling in product data from woocommerce and am trying to loop/map over the variations. The end goal is to have a dropdown (or radio buttons or anything really) for each variation as in:

Size: S M L

Color: red blue green

Here is the data I get from woocommerce and below, my attempt of getting it to work.

Data:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allWcProducts": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "variations": [
              {
                "id": 14,
                "attributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "color",
                    "option": "red"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "size",
                    "option": "S"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": 15,
                "attributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "color",
                    "option": "red"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "size",
                    "option": "M"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": 16,
                "attributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "color",
                    "option": "red"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "size",
                    "option": "L"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": 17,
                "attributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "color",
                    "option": "blue"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "size",
                    "option": "S"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": 18,
                "attributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "color",
                    "option": "blue"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "size",
                    "option": "M"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": 19,
                "attributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "color",
                    "option": "blue"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "size",
                    "option": "L"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": 20,
                "attributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "color",
                    "option": "green"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "size",
                    "option": "S"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": 21,
                "attributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "color",
                    "option": "green"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "size",
                    "option": "M"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": 22,
                "attributes": [
                  {
                    "name": "color",
                    "option": "green"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "size",
                    "option": "L"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My attempt that currently only outputs:

color

red

M

```
.....
    const post = this.props.data.wcProducts
......
{
  post.variations.map((variations, i) => (
    <div key={`${post.variations} ${i}`}>
      <p>{post.variations[i].attributes[0].name}</p>

      {post.variations[i].attributes.map((wcProducts, i) => (
        <div key={`${post.variations} ${i}`}>
          <p>{post.variations[i].attributes[i].option}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Tried switching around pretty much everything and it just gets more confusing to me so any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this:

```js
const data = { "allWcProducts": { "edges": [ { "node": { "variations": [ { "id": 14, "attributes": [ { "name": "color", "option": "red" }, { "name": "size", "option": "S" } ] }, { "id": 15, "attributes": [ { "name": "color", "option": "red" }, { "name": "size", "option": "M" } ] }, { "id": 16, "attributes": [ { "name": "color", "option": "red" }, { "name": "size", "option": "L" } ] }, { "id": 17, "attributes": [ { "name": "color", "option": "blue" }, { "name": "size", "option": "S" } ] }, { "id": 18, "attributes": [ { "name": "color", "option": "blue" }, { "name": "size", "option": "M" } ] }, { "id": 19, "attributes": [ { "name": "color", "option": "blue" }, { "name": "size", "option": "L" } ] }, { "id": 20, "attributes": [ { "name": "color", "option": "green" }, { "name": "size", "option": "S" } ] }, { "id": 21, "attributes": [ { "name": "color", "option": "green" }, { "name": "size", "option": "M" } ] }, { "id": 22, "attributes": [ { "name": "color", "option": "green" }, { "name": "size", "option": "L" } ] } ] } } ] } } 

const getOptions = data => {
  const result = data.allWcProducts.edges.reduce((r,{node}) => 
     node.variations.forEach(({attributes}) =>
        attributes.forEach(({name, option}) =>
           r[name] ? r[name].add(option) : r[name] = new Set([option]))) || r, {})
  return Object.entries(result).reduce((r, c) => (r[c[0]] = [...c[1]]) && r, {})
}

console.log(getOptions(data))
```

It will dynamically create the array of the options and the main idea here is the use of the ES6 [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which takes care of keeping the values unique.

The last `reduce` is due to the results coming in a Set form and we are converting them to arrays.

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot! Will need to wrap my head around it to properly understand it ;)